# Does php's include option do a partial page refresh?

Tags: php, ajax, include

I've started using PHP locally and notice that if I use include files within a main `index.php` file, the whole page does not refresh when I click a button/link that will include a new/updated include file.  My question is, is php's include option like ajax and only does a partial page refresh?  If so, am I better off using just plain php or should I stick with ajax?

Comment: What? I'm completely lost what is your question.

Comment: PHP's include works precisely the same as if you were to include the text of the included file.  More precisely, the following are equivalent: `<? echo "before"; include('lib.php'); echo "after"; ?>` and `<? echo "before; ?> [contents of lib.php] <? echo "after"; ?>`.  If you post a code sample someone here might be able to help with whatever is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

PHP code is interpreted server-side so it doesn't use AJAX like client-side JavaScript. Clicking a link will request a new page, and PHP will interpret the requested files and return the output. You're likely not experiencing refresh times because you're working locally. If you take a look at the Network tab of Chrome Developer tools you'll see the refresh take place.

Answer (score 0):

No, only AJAX do partial page refresh. Because you're programming in localhost and you're including the same file in multiple pages, you won't notice the loading time and it looks like nothing has changed (on  the browser).

Include function just includes the content of a php file in the one where it was called, all PHP code is done on the server-side, so the content is included in server side and sent all of it to the client (no ajax).

So, stick with ajax because it's the only way to do partial refreshing.